# Heroku src refspec master does not match any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am looking to deploy to Heroku, however I receive an error when running the command `git push heroku master`

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aytaken.git'
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means there's no master branch. Rename your default branch to `master` or check your branch name and it should work.